# Stripe Android - Attach Card To Customer After Setup Intent

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I'm working with stripe integration. To add and save card. For entering card details i'm using stripe's default **AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter** . After setup intent my card is not attached to the customer and it is not not displayed in stripe console as well.

1. Is there any way to automatically attach card after setup intent (stripe.confirmSetupIntent) ?
2. Also i'm **adding a footer layout to AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter**. and the footer layout has a checkbox. is there any way to get the checkbox checked,unchecked value. Even after initialization, i always get null

**StripeActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stripe_latest);
        initMethod();
        findElements();

        // Get ephemeralKey
        CustomerSession.initCustomerSession(this, (s, ephemeralKeyUpdateListener) -> getEphemeralKey(ephemeralKeyUpdateListener, s));

        // Use the publishable key from the server to initialize the Stripe instance.
        stripe = new Stripe(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.stripe_publishable_key));


        // launch stripe add card ui
        new AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter(StripeAddCardActivityDup.this).startForResult(
                new AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Args.Builder()
           .setAddPaymentMethodFooter(R.layout.footer_layout) // --> get the value of checkbox
                     .build());
    
       // initialize the checkbox, in footer layout
         saveCard = findViewById(R.id.saveCard);
           if(saveCard !=null){
                    if(saveCard.isChecked()){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "checkbox is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "checkbox is not checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "checkbox is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        messageHandler.lock(StripeAddCardActivityDup.this);
        if (requestCode == AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.REQUEST_CODE) {    // result of AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter. get payment id and send to setupintent
            final AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Result result =
                    AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Result.fromIntent(data);
            if (result instanceof AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Result.Success) {
                final AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Result.Success successResult =
                        (AddPaymentMethodActivityStarter.Result.Success) result;
                setUpIntent(successResult.getPaymentMethod().id);
            }

        } else if (requestCode == 50001) { // result of setup intent
            WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(this);

            // Handle the result of stripe.confirmSetupIntent
            stripe.onSetupResult(requestCode, data, new ApiResultCallback<SetupIntentResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull SetupIntentResult result) {
                    SetupIntent setupIntent = result.getIntent();
                    SetupIntent.Status status = setupIntent.getStatus();
                    if (status == SetupIntent.Status.Succeeded) {
                        // Setup completed successfully
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            if (weakActivity.get() != null) {
                               attachCustomer(setupIntent.getPaymentMethodId()); // --> manually attaching the card to customer after setup intent using "attachPaymentMethod"
                            }
                        });
                    } else if (status == SetupIntent.Status.RequiresPaymentMethod) {
                        // Setup failed – allow retrying using a different payment method
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
                            if (activity != null) {
                                stripeErrorAlert(setupIntent.getLastSetupError().getMessage());
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // Setup request failed – allow retrying using the same payment method
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
                        if (activity != null) {
                            stripeErrorAlert(e.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    // method to confirm setup intent
    public void setUpIntent(String paymentMethodId) {
        BackgroundExecutor.execute(new BackgroundExecutor.Task("", 0, "") {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                try {
                    messageHandler.lock(StripeAddCardActivityDup.this);
                    // retrofit WS to get client secret
                    SetupIntentModel intentModel = driverService.getSetupIntent(new StripeSetupIntentRequest(getString(R.string.stripe_customer_id)));
                    
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                        ConfirmSetupIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmSetupIntentParams.create(paymentMethodId, intentModel.getClientSecret(),"redirect://stripe");
                        stripe.confirmSetupIntent(StripeAddCardActivityDup.this, confirmParams);
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.logError(AppConstants.GENERAL_TAG, e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

// attach card to customer
     private void attachCustomer(String paymentId){
            CustomerSession.getInstance().attachPaymentMethod(paymentId, new CustomerSession.PaymentMethodRetrievalListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPaymentMethodRetrieved(@NotNull PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
                    messageHandler.showAlert(getString(R.string.card_was_successful_added), getString(R.string.ok), "", v -> finish(),null);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onError(int i, @NotNull String s, @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable StripeError stripeError) {
                    String errorMsg = getString(R.string.card_wasnt_successful_added)+"-"+stripeError.toString();
                    messageHandler.showAlert(errorMsg, getString(R.string.ok), "", v -> finish(),null);
                }
            });
        }
```

**footer_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/saveCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="save card" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you pass `customer` and `usage` to the SetupIntent when you create it on the backend server, the payment method used should get automatically attached to the customer associated with the SetupIntent that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot @karllekko. Passing customer and usage  in backend server worked and in app, card is automatically attached to customer

Comment: Is there any way , to get the footer layout events in activity? I tried initializing the checkbox present in footer layout after I launch the stripe add card class. But the checkbox value is coming as null.